# In OCI python SDK what is the function for waiting until a stack creation complete?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any built-in function in OCI python SDK for waiting until stack creation operation is complete?

For instance, this is the method.

`oci.resource_manager.create_stack(create_stack_details)`

for the above method, I want a waiter method to wait until this operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

create stack is a synchronous operation. The python function will return the successful response only after the stack create operation is complete. So there is no need to have a waiter function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt 'Waiters' class.

This can be used for any resource depending on required property and state. You can even write custom function to handle your own logic for terminating the wait.

Details here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.90.0/api/waiters.html